# select a row index weighted by value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random, python-3.8

weight dictionary: `{1:0.1, 2:0.9}` (there is a 10% probability of an item with the value 1 of being selected, 90% with value 2)

exmple value row: `[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1]` (the will only be 0s and values that are contained in the dictionary)

The output should be a randomly chosen index

For the example row, the probabilities of the index of being selected for each item in the row should be `[0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0.9, 0.05]` (note that since the row contains two different `1` elements, each of them should have a prob of 0.05 of being selected, since the weight counts towards an item with that value being selected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.select` here.

```
wt = {1:0.1, 2:0.9}
a = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1])
choicelist = [a==i for i in wt.keys()]
condlist = [v/np.count_nonzero(a==k) for k,v in wt.items()]
np.select(choicelist, condlist)
# array([0.  , 0.  , 0.05, 0.  , 0.9 , 0.05])
```

Comment: unfortunatelly, this results in a division by 0 if a key is not represented in a row. For example, try with `wt = {1:0.1, 2:0.9, 3:0.1}`

Comment: Using `condlist = [v/np.count_nonzero(a==k) if np.count_nonzero(a==k) > 0 else 0 for k,v in wt.items()]` works

Comment: also, using `np.isclose` was safer than using equality in my case

Comment: also, if you are going to run it on a 200k x 200k df, it's gonna take some time